# Adding a potentiometer to a motor circuit to control speed

Tags: dc-motor, potentiometer

How can I add a potentiometer to control the speed of this motor in this circuit? It is a 3-12V DC Motor 2RPM max.

I am unsure as to what kind of Potentiometer to use, or how to include it into this circuit. If someone can help me out that would be really awesome!

Thanks in advance!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7nYbq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Solution:** Place the potentiometer (POT) *in series* right after the 12V DC source's positive terminal.
2. **Explanation:** If you look at the circuit to the left of our proposed POT and consider it a black box, the black box has some equivalent impedance. By placing a POT in series with the black box, you have a series connection of one DC source and two impedances.

   -As you increase the resistance of the POT, the POT will take on a larger voltage drop and it will leave a smaller voltage drop for the black box.

   -As you decrease the resistance of the POT, the POT will take on a smaller voltage drop and it will leave a larger voltage drop for the black box.

   You can see that by varying the amount of voltage that our POT dissipates as heat, we can directly vary the amount of voltage that will be left for the motor circuit.
3. **As for picking the correct POT?** You will need to find the equivalent impedance of the black box first (\$Z_{BlackBox}\$). Then you take the equivalent impedance of the black box, and plug it into the voltage divider formula with an unknown resistance (\$R_{POT}\$) modeling our mystery POT. The voltage which you are solving for with the voltage divider should be the voltage across the black-box impedance (\$V_{BlackBox}\$). Solve for \$R_{POT}\$ when \$V_{BlackBox}\$=3V and then solve again for \$R_{POT}\$ when \$V_{BlackBox}\$=12V. This will give you the necessary resistance range for your POT.

Comment: An electronic motor speed controller is probably cheaper. Eg.: http://www.amazon.co.uk/12V-24V-Motor-Speed-Control-Controller/dp/B008MT8WZ6%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAILSHYYTFIVPWUY6Q%26tag%3Dduc08-21%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3DB008MT8WZ6

Comment: how would the voltage divider formula look?

Comment: @jippie will that work with my motor?

Comment: You haven't specified the current your motors draw. If it's anything much, a standard pot won't handle it - the point where the wiper makes contact with the resistive element will develop a burned spot. There are pots made for this sort of thing, and they are called "rheostats". You're better off getting a variable output power supply to replace your fixed 12-volt unit.

Comment: @Adjit is this for a class or for a real-world application? Also, the voltage divider formula is the basic formula you learn in an introductory circuits course. What is your academic background?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast We don't know if this is a problem for a class or a real-world application. Your point is valid in that the current handling of a POT will not be sufficient for high current loads. But in a theoretical classroom setting... ;)

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast the motor I am using has a .5A stall current and .95mA for no load current @ max efficiency. This is the motor : http://www.servocity.com/html/1_rpm_gear_motor.html

Comment: @EEIngenuity my academic background is comp sci, this is merely a project I decided to take on.